# Eclipse Neon: Icons are not disabled

Tags: 16.04, icons, eclipse

**Problem:**

I try to explain the problem I am having with Eclipse: Well, as shown in my attached screenshot all Icons seems to be enabled. But normally some Icons are disabled. For Example: When the Debugger is in running, you cannot press the resume button, but the resume button and the Stop button appear like an enabled button. Nevertheless just one of them is clickable.

[image: Icons]

So in summary eclipses logic behind the Icons is working, but eclipse does not change the visual style of a button, when it is disabled (not clickable).

**Question:**

Does anybody know how to force eclipse to show an disabled icon, when the button is disabled and an enabled icon, when the button is enabled?

**Further information:**

- Eclipse Version: Eclipse Neon
- Ubuntu Version: Ubuntu 16.04 LTS
- Java Version: Java 8 (openjdk)

**What I have already tried to do:**

- I tried using Eclipse Mars. But is has the same behavior than Neon.
- **I tried using Eclipse Luna. This works pretty fine. All siabled buttons are grayed out.**
- I reported this bug to eclipse: https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=501878

Comment: Which JDK are you using?

Comment: Hey Andriod Dev, I inserted my JDK version within my Question.

Comment: Can you try a different version of Eclipse? It works fine for me. (I'm using Luna on 14.04 with the OpenJDK 8)

Comment: Hey Andriod Dev. I tested Eclipse Mars and Luna and inserted the result within my question.

Comment: Hrmmm.... Maybe you want to report a bug to the Eclipse team?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This problem is caused by the use of GTK3 in newer ubuntu versions with SWT programs.

You can set a flag in your .profile to make SWT Programms like Eclipse use GTK2 for now.

1. Open your `.profile` file, located in your home folder.
2. Add `export SWT_GTK3=0` to the end of the file.

your file should now look similar to this (that is actually my .profile file):

```
# ~/.profile: executed by the command interpreter for login shells.
# This file is not read by bash(1), if ~/.bash_profile or ~/.bash_login
# exists.
# see /usr/share/doc/bash/examples/startup-files for examples.
# the files are located in the bash-doc package.

# the default umask is set in /etc/profile; for setting the umask
# for ssh logins, install and configure the libpam-umask package.
#umask 022

# if running bash
if [ -n "$BASH_VERSION" ]; then
    # include .bashrc if it exists
    if [ -f "$HOME/.bashrc" ]; then
    . "$HOME/.bashrc"
    fi
fi

# set PATH so it includes user's private bin if it exists
if [ -d "$HOME/bin" ] ; then
    PATH="$HOME/bin:$PATH"
fi

### User changes
# disable GTK3 for Eclipse and other SWT programs.
export SWT_GTK3=0 

# disable overlay scrollbars globally for this user.
export GTK_OVERLAY_SCROLLING=0
```

3. Save file.
4. Logout current user and log back in.

If you start Eclipse now, you can see disabled icons greyed out.

Happy coding.

Comment: Thank you for providing your well described workaround. I marked your question as solution.